# UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '`'

Tags: python-3.x, load, pickle, word2vec

Tried use pretrained model for russian lang. from 
https://wikipedia2vec.github.io/wikipedia2vec/pretrained/

But can't load model from pkl file. 
Tried to use other encoders as cp1251, latin1, windows-1252. Unfortunately, it drops down.

```py
model = Word2Vec.load_word2vec_format('ruwiki_20180420_100d.pkl')

UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '`'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the text on the page you've referenced, https://wikipedia2vec.github.io/wikipedia2vec/pretrained/, the binary files there should be loaded with `Wikipedia2Vec.load()`.

Only the other text files there, with suffixes `.txt`, can be loaded with `gensim`'s `load_word2vec_format()` method.

Either use `Wikipedia2Vec.load()` with the file you've mentioned, or try the text file variants instead.